# How we can Refactor Switch case statement when working with Primitives

Tags: c#, switch-statement, refactoring

This piece of code is violating the Open and Closed Principle, is there any way we can refactor this code as each year we add more cases.

```
  public ISampleDataEnhancer GetEnhancer(Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        var typeEnhancer = ((Data.BaseSampleData)data["DataObject"]).TypeOfEnhancer;

        switch (typeEnhancer)
        {
            case "V2018.SampleA":
                {
                    return new ADataEnhancer2018();
                }

            case "V2018.SampleB":
                {
                    return new BDataEnhancer2018();
                }

            case "V2019.SampleA":
                {
                    return new ADataEnhancer2019();
                }

            case "V2019.SampleB":
                {
                    return new GRDataEnhancer2019();
                }

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```